# Pandas Dataframe reporting 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128) when running KNN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, ascii

I'm running KNN from sk-learn using python and pandas. However, the system reports `target_names = [u'%s' % l for l in labels]`and`'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)` I'm suspecting that the problem could be potentially caused by my target column which is TX_FINAL_WORK_CODE_STR. My dataframe looks like the following

[image]

The highlighted column is the one that might cause the problem

I have tried to use the following code to solve the problem

1. `df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\daizh\\Desktop\Ren\\txdot\\work_hist.csv", encoding='utf-8')`. This is the traceback `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 6: invalid start byte`
2. `df14['TX_FINAL_WORK_CODE_STR']=df14['TX_FINAL_WORK_CODE_STR'].decode('utf-8')`. This is the traceback `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribut 'decode'`
3. `df14['TX_FINAL_WORK_CODE_STR']=df14['TX_FINAL_WORK_CODE_STR'].astype('unicode')` This is the traceback `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Please try to change your encoding to: `encoding = "cp1252"` while reading your csv file.

Comment: @John Doe, Dear John, Just tried your code, however, the system showed a traceback at the very first line `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: I think john's idea is right. Probably what you use just isn't a mulitbyte encoding. If you don't know, exactly how it is encoded, you could try to open it in an editor like notepad++ and let it figure out, what it is. Then if you go on save it usually reveals it's guess what the encoding is. You should also check in the editor if the content of the file is displayed correctly (the special characters e.g. with accents or umlauts). If not, test some encodings, the editor supports. Once you found the correct one, just use the option, John proposed and replace the encoding string.

Comment: Dear @jottbe, if i open the csv file with notpad++, beside "Save as type" it shows Normal text file "*.txt" does this tell me the encoding type of the original file?

Comment: Ok, in `notepad++ ` I think there is an extra menu entry, where you can change the encoding. There you should see a check mark on the encoding, the editor is using and here you could also change the encoding.

Comment: @yihaoren : Try calling read_csv with encoding='latin1', encoding='iso-8859-1' (or encoding='cp1252') These are some of the various encodings found on Windows.

Comment: @jottbe I tried using notepad++ to find the encoding type. I believe notepad++ showed ANSI. I also tried to convert it to utf-8 using notepad++. however python got a memory error when running the new file

Comment: @John Doe thanks for your reply. I actually tried all those but still run into the same traceback. `df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\daizh\\Desktop\Ren\\txdot\\work_hist.csv", encoding='cp1252')` This is how i write my code. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: @yihaoren : Please check if the file is UTF-8 with BOM. If so, save as UTF-8 without BOM (e.g. Notepad++; Encoding > Convert to UTF-8 -> option without  BOM)

Comment: @yihaoren: https://wellsr.com/python/reading-csv-files-with-the-python-csv-module/#DetectingBOM